# Double for loop to save several files using R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am trying to do a “for loop” to generate files based on the column "group". I want to create a file for each group.  My data is much bigger, but a sample would be:

```
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
group = c(3,1,3,2,1,3,1,2,4,4)
weight = c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
index1 = c(50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50)
index2 = c(50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50)
data = data.frame(id,group,weight,index1,index2)
for (i in unique(data$group)){
for (j in 1:nrow(data)){
data$weight[j] = ifelse(data$group[j] == data$group[i], 0,data$weight[j])
data$index1[j] = ifelse(data$group[j] == data$group[i], 0,50)
data$index2[j] = ifelse(data$group[j] == data$group[i], 5,50)
}
write.table(data,paste("/home/paulaf/test/",data$group[i],".txt",sep=""),
               quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)}
```

It seems to work, but it doesn’t write all the files. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paula,

That code is actually writing four files. But you're overwriting one of those files, so you're only ending up with three.

When you name the file with `paste`, you're using `data$group[i]` to generate the name.  If you look at those name by using `cat()` or something similar, you'll notice you have two `3.txt` files.

```
/home/paulaf/test/3.txt 
/home/paulaf/test/3.txt 
/home/paulaf/test/1.txt 
/home/paulaf/test/2.txt
```

So, that's why your not getting all of you files. Your first 3.txt is overwritten.

Looking a bit more closely at your `data` object, you can see why this happened. 
Your `i` in your loops is going to have the values 3, 1, 2, and 4. By plugging 1-4 into `data$group[i]`, you're actually pulling out the value of the 1-4th rows in the `data$group`.  Notice that the first and third rows are both group 3.

```
   id group weight index1 index2
1   1     3      0     50     50
2   2     1      0     50     50
3   3     3      0     50     50
4   4     2      0      0      5
5   5     1      0     50     50
6   6     3      0     50     50
7   7     1      0     50     50
8   8     2      0      0      5
9   9     4     18     50     50
10 10     4     19     50     50
```

Maybe replace your `write.table()` with this:

```
write.table(data,paste("/home/paulaf/test/",i,".txt",sep=""),
               quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)
```

And one other note to save you future headache: It's often helpful to print some of your variables to the console. It's just a way to get some insight into what's happening.

Also, good luck, keep working with R, you're doing great!

Answer (score 1):

`unique(data$group)` is a vector of length 4. `data$group` has a length of 10. You're setting the filenames to the first 4 values of `data$group` instead of the unique values of `data$group`.

Try replacing `data$group[i]` with just `i` inside the `paste` that generates the filename, e.g.

```
for (i in unique(data$group)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(data)){
    data$weight[j] = ifelse(data$group[j] == data$group[i], 0,data$weight[j])
    data$index1[j] = ifelse(data$group[j] == data$group[i], 0,50)
    data$index2[j] = ifelse(data$group[j] == data$group[i], 5,50)
  }
  fileName = paste("/home/paulaf/test/",i,".txt",sep="")
  write.table(data,fileName,quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very simple. Inside your `write.table` function, you're pasting the name using `data$group[i]`, but your outside loop is not looping over the indices of the unique groups, but over the group names themselves. Your  `i`s are `3 1 2 4`, so calling `data$group[i]` for each of those will result in `3, 3, 1, 2`, which means all the filenames are all wrong (one file is replaced and you end up with only 3, for this sample). The solution is then:

```
write.table(data,paste("/home/paulaf/test/",i,".txt",sep=""),
               quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)}
```

It's also *slightly more efficiently* (and easier to read, imho) to use `paste0`, so:

```
write.table(data,paste0("/home/paulaf/test/",i,".txt"),
               quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=T)}
```